# ssh with kerberos ticket

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, kerberos

When I log in to a server using OpenSSH, generated the Kerberos ticket on the /tmp/krb5cc_.

1 - how to generate this ticket and where is the conf file to create this ticket?

2 - How to generate the kerberos ticket with a forwardable flag when I log in to a server using OpenSSH?

3 - I want to ssh to 3 different servers via Kerberos ticket. When I log into the server1 using a password, will create the Kerberos ticket for me. After I use this ticket for the ssh to server2 and this ticket following me. Finally, I will passwordless-ssh to server3 using ticket once again.

As a summary I log in use password to server1 after the jump to server2 not using password via Kerberos ticket after then I will ssh without the password to the third server as well as the second server.

Comment: How to forward kerberos ssh ticket to next server - http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4981397

Answer (score 1):

in modern linux systems you're using some pam module to that. 
par of the info you seek is in the man page of said module.

unless you;re on a fedora derived system, the most used one seems to be :
https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/pam-krb5/pam-krb5.html
search for appefaults in the above page (a section in /etc/krb5.conf).

```
ccache=<pattern>
```

would answer the second part of your question number 1, the first part would be the pam module.

```
forwardable = True
```

would answer number 2,can be set  appdefaults  or libdefaults section of /etc/krb5/conf.

number 3 has to do with ssh 
man ssh or ssh_config would reveal either  use -K (ssh -K )  or set GSSAPIDelegateCredentials=yes and  GSSAPIAuthentication=yes  in ~/.ssh/config (either globally --not a good idea-- or on per host/domain)

see the man pages (ssh, pam_kr5,krb5.conf.kinit) for more info.